# How to switch between different activities and keep service going

Tags: android, service

I am a google glass developer.(and I am Chinese student...poor English)

I have to get bluetooth information in background, keeping update, show it on my google glass, but I can't keep my bluetooth service running when I switch my activities.(because every activity should show the latest bluetooth information.)

I want to know :

how can I let my service keep live when I switch different activities?

Comment: It should (with start_sticky) ... How you're starting the service

Answer (score 0):

What you need is to bind the running service to the upcoming activity.

Binding is essentially making the activity start the service if it is not started already or get the running instance if it is already running, 
[Read more here.](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html)